# cyrus-imap SSL error

Tags: email, openssl, cyrus

We have recently launched a site and a few days ago the mail.log file started to grow incredibly quickly (2gb per day). I've just had a look at log file and the lines below below are repeated thousands of time:

```
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/imaps[6138]: Fatal error: imaps: required OpenSSL options not present
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/master[9410]: process 6138 exited, status 75
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/master[9410]: service imaps pid 6138 in READY state: terminated abnormally
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/master[6139]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus/bin/imapd
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/imaps[6139]: executed
Jul  3 17:00:23 ubuntu cyrus/imaps[6139]: imaps: required OpenSSL options not present
```

I'm not a systems admin expert and the email was setup be a friend. Is there a quick fix for this until we have time to delve deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.  You can comment out the `imaps` line in /etc/cyrus.conf.  This assumes that you don't care about incoming IMAP connections on SSL (but, then, it's not working anyway, as the `imaps` daemon is terminating abnormally).

In more detail:

Your line in /etc/cyrus.conf will look something like:

```
 imaps      cmd="imapd -s" listen="imaps" prefork=10
```

You can put a `#` at the beginning of the line:

```
 # imaps        cmd="imapd -s" listen="imaps" prefork=10
```

And then reload cyrus-imapd.  Something like `/etc/init.d/cyrus-imapd reload`, perhaps depending on what distribution you have.

Comment: Thats stopped the logging, thanks! Can you briefly explain why those errors were been logged so often (hundreds per minute!). Is there some sort of spam attack going on?

Comment: It's not an attack.  It's a misconfiguration of the cyrus-imapd server.  Without seeing your configs, it's impossible to say what's wrong, but one guess would be that you've turned on IMAP SSL (with that `imaps` line), but didn't specify the public/private keys that's required for SSL (i.e., there should be lines in the `/etc/imapd.conf` file that start with `tls_`, such as `tls_key_file` and `tls_cert_file`.)  The lines repeat because the cyrus master process keeps trying to start imaps, but fails immediately because of the misconfiguration.

Comment: Yes, arguably, it would be better if cyrus-master just stops trying to start up the misconfigured child procs instead of spewing a zillion lines into logs.

Comment: ok thanks for the help, the server is immediately 10 times faster. We're moving server and going to just host the emails with gmail business account because configuring ourselves has caused too many problems

Comment: The Cyrus server will be better about this in version 2.5, when it's released.  We've done a lot of work on improving the master process (well, Greg Banks has to be more specific)

Comment: @Mark, you might want to accept this answer by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it, thus driving the reputation system for both you and cjc, and stopping the question floating around forever like a querulous albatross.  My apologies if you already know this.